# Как узнать какие таблицы ссылаются на значение?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Нужно узнать какие таблицы ссылаются на значение, которое у них указано как "Foreign Key"?

Comment: Посмотрите, возможно поможет - https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/catalog-pg-constraint

Comment: Узнать с помощью чего? Можно написать универсальный запрос, используя системные каталоги, а можно использовать пользовательский интерфейс навороченной программы-клиента вроде DataGrip.

Answer (score 0):

Свойства -> Зависимая таблица -> зависимая колонка